# Visual Studio 2013 changes Shortcuts Randomly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.
The "Default Collection of Settings" are set to "C#"

Until a few weeks ago everything worked fine.
Then, from one day to another, the Search-Shortcut changed from **Ctrl+F** to **Alt+F3**. I didn't knew why, and because I was at a relatively important project, I let everything as it was.

But now, this morning, it happened again.
I saved the Project, Checked in everything into the TFS 2012, Checked out for the latest version.
Then I opened a file and made some changes and then I wanted to save it.

But **Ctrl+s** didn't do anything.
Well, I looked under "File", and I saw, that the shortcut had changed:
It was no longer **Ctrl+s** but now it was **Shift+F12**.

So I went to "Tools -> Import and Export settings -> Reset" and I resetted all Settings.

I reopened the Visual Studio and voilà, everything as before: Search at Ctrl+F, Save at Ctrl+S, like nothing happened.

My Question is now: Why did something like this happen? I never made any changes to the shortcuts and I didn't change anything else willingly.

Has anyone faced this issue too? I found nothing like this at Google...

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Any plugins or extensions installed? Some change the keyboard settings if you allow it.

Comment: No Plugins installed except of Sandcastle plugin (SHFB), but everyone else in the team has the same and no issues.

Comment: Are you using a multi-user (corporate, for example) license?

Comment: Afaik we're using multiple single-PC-Licenses, but to make sure I'll ask our infrastructure tomorrow.